Is ECharts capable of creating a timelines chart similar to vasturiano timelines-chart
I am trying to use EChart to create a timelines-chart similar to charts produced by [Vasturiano's D3 timelines-chart]
(https://github.com/vasturiano/timelines-chart?tab=readme-ov-file)
I have been able to generate a "stepped" chart so to speak Stair Steps Timeline
(https://i.sstatic.net/FylfbI4V.png)
But my end product needs to look like this Stacked Timeline by 24 hour clock
(https://i.sstatic.net/Jf3yuNp2.png)
I basically need to plot each day on the y-axis but the hours for each day need to use the same x-axis and not create a separate new time each day in the data.
Am I able to do this in ECharts or do I need to use D3

yes, you can do this in eCharts. I have done the same based on this example
